DuckDB to_df() error Casting value to type DECIMAL(7,2) failed: value is out of range
DuckDB SQL SUM query returns error:

Casting value to type DECIMAL(7,2) failed: value is out of range

I'm trying to run the following query using DuckDB:
df_duckdb = duckdb.sql(f"""
    SELECT 'client', month, year,  SUM(income)AS total_value
    from df
    group by 'client', month, year
    """).to_df()

However, I get an error:

InvalidInputException: Invalid Input Error: Failed to cast value: Casting value "102188.25" to type DECIMAL(7,2) failed: value is out of range

This error also occurs when I try to use .to_csv().
This is ok:
grouped_df = copy_df.groupby(['client', 'month', 'year']).agg(
        {'income': 'sum'}).reset_index()

example pandas df:
    data = [
    ["95/01/24/FV", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-10", 2024, 1, "2024-03-15", 2024, 3, "Impact - dostawa", 4759, "Impact - dostawa", "TAK", 1217619, "1756", 98192, 7425.00, 27, 192.50, 5197.50],
    ["95/01/24/FV", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-10", 2024, 1, "2024-03-15", 2024, 3, "Impact - dostawa", 4759, "Impact - dostawa", "TAK", 1217619, "1879", 102236, 11674.80, 18, 454.02, 8172.36],
    ["95/01/24/FV", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-10", 2024, 1, "2024-03-15", 2024, 3, "Impact - dostawa", 4759, "Impact - dostawa", "TAK", 1217619, "1864", 102234, 102188.25, 27, 2649.33, 71531.91],
    ["95/01/24/FV", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-10", 2024, 1, "2024-03-15", 2024, 3, "Impact - dostawa", 4759, "Impact - dostawa", "TAK", 1217619, "1880", 102237, 5837.40, 9, 454.02, 4086.18],
    ["95/01/24/FV", "2024-01-17", "2024-01-10", "2024-01-10", 2024, 1, "2024-03-15", 2024, 3, "Impact - dostawa", 4759, "Impact - dostawa", "TAK", 1217619, "1812", 105182, 61874.55, 27, 1604.16, 43312.32]
]

columns = [
    "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "year", "month", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "client",
    "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "income", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

Could someone please advise on how to resolve this issue?

Can you provide example df = ... code in order to reproduce this error?

The RDBMS I know use DECIMAL(p,s) like this: p defines the total number of digits, and s the number of digits (part of that total) that come after the decimal point. So DECIMAL(7,2) means 7 digits overall, 2 after the decimal point - and thus 5 before the decimal point - and that's just not enough precision to handle a value of 102188.25. Solution: use a bigger number of digits - e.g. use DECIMAL(12,2) or something like that

It works when I save data to a .csv file and read it again into a DataFrame. How can I use DECIMAL(12,2)? Casting in duckdb.sql doesn't work for me.

It could be a bug. Is df a pandas dataframe? A polars dataframe? Providing a minimal reproducible example would be the first step in helping figure out the issue.

I added an example DataFrame. It's a pandas DataFrame; the original DataFrame has more than 100,000 rows.
